# Bandpass Filter Output & Fourier Transform

Tags: python, fft, noise-reduction, butterworth, bandpass-filter

I'm trying ko eliminate noise and some other frequencies that I do not require from this waveform:
[image: trimmed signal]

As you can see in the picture below, it has a lot of noise in it:
[image: noise]

I apply the fast fourier transform using numpy to convert this into frequency domain: (channelA and time are numpy arrays, channelA storing voltage values)

```
fY = np.fft.fft(channelA)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(channelA), time[1]-time[0])
```

Here is the transform:
[image: fft]
When zoomed in:
[image: fft zoomed]
I apply a butterworth bandpass filter using scipy in python. Here is the code:

```
low = 100 / (0.5 * 2e6)   # nyq = 1/2 * fs
high = 1e3 / (0.5 * 2e6)
sos = sp.butter(1, [low, high], btype='bandpass', output='sos')
y = sp.sosfiltfilt(sos, channelA)
```

Here my sampling rate is 2M (2e6), and my passband frequencies are 100-1kHz.
After applying the filter, the signal seems to have lost the noise but however the voltage at the start goes negative. I do not understand why. Can someone explain why this is happening?
[image: filtered signal]
Zoomed in to show no noise left:
[image: no noise]

Voltage goes negative when I apply the highpass filter. If I only apply the lowpass filter, the noise gets eliminated. (highpass and lowpass filters can be applied using the same function)

This is the transform of the filtered signal:
[image: filtered fft]
Zoomed in:
[image: filtered fft zoomed]

As can be seen, frequencies less than 100Hz are still present and frequencies around 350Hz have been removed. I'm trying to get a focus on frequencies around 350-400Hz and want to eliminate the rest of the frequencies while not distorting the signal. Why is this happening and what should I do to achieve this?

P.S. I'm sorry the post is kind of long but I don't have another way of explaining this.

Comment: Hi, `sos = sp.butter(1, [low, high], btype='bandpass', output='sos')` is a bandpass filter. It discards high frequency noise and low frequencies. The average of the signal is frequency 0 : as a bandpass filter is applied, the average is cleared and the signal likely features both positive and negative values. Could you try the lowpass fliter usign the higher frequency 1kHz ? `sos = sp.butter(1, high, btype='lowpass', output='sos')`

Comment: @francis When I do that, the noise is eliminated - yes. But I want to eliminate the low frequencies seen on the fourier transform of the original signal as well. I am not being able to do that. I understand how the average can get cleared but then shouldn't the transform of the filtered signal not show the low frequencies?

Comment: The low frequencies have been significantly reduced. Ay 25Hz, it was 2500-3000, while it is likely 200 after. The slope of the lowpass Butterworth filter is +20dB/decade. A a factor of 4 between 25Hz and 100Hz is about half a decade, say 10-12dB : it is not that much https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel . Low frequencies are not zeroed. To eliminate the low frequencies, you may apply the high pass filter multiple times. Take a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.buttord.html#scipy.signal.buttord  it prodives tuned parameters for the Butterworth filter.

Comment: @francis I see what you mean. Thanks!